# Help with auto Punkin farm/melon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to build this ([Punkin/melon farm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhhIhGDfYWc)) on my world but I want to build a huge tower of it but I don't know how I can transport the items down to a chest without using more than a 100 (example) hoppers. ( I don't have enough iron to build the hoppers all the way down) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

drop them in a water stream using droppers

or have a chest/hopper cart go around to collect them

this last option will also use iron for the tracks though

Answer (score 1):

No iron then use water stream Credit to person above me it will be to slow after that on the botton of the tower add a hopper so when the things you get fall in the hopper it gets on the chest that is on the cart with the tracks and then you might as well use a flipflop system so the cart goes to the place you want it to be collect those things and it will go back thats how i build one it works great and you need powered rails that are needed red stone sticks and gold so you need alot of gold.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to include some punctuation and a bit more detail to help people to understand it?